# C# (.net) RegEx.Match Substring between newlines - using newline as positive lookahead limit

Tags: c#, .net, regex, newline, regex-lookarounds

I have been tinkering with RegEx and got some great results and I want to keep using it.

Right now I am stuck at finding a string that is set between 2 newlines. Here is the sample target text (note this is one of thousands of possible texts):

```
Substance information in Wikipedia
FORMULA
CH2O
Grafik
Molar mass: 30,03 g/mol
```

The target is "CH2O".

I tried `(?<=FORMULA).*(?=Grafik)` with `RegexOptions.Singleline` and it starts right after `FORMULA` but goes all the way down and ignores `Grafik`.

I tried it without singleline but it returns nothing since the `.` stops at the `\n`. Since I want the newline as a limit, the following has no singleline.

The closest I have gotten were these:

```
(?<=FORMULA)[\w\W]+(?=Grafik)
(?<=FORMULA)[\w\W]*(?=Grafik)
```

However, if the `Grafik` changes, I'd like to track the newline instead of it.

`(?<=FORMULA)[\w\W]*(?=\n)` or `(?<=FORMULA)[\w\W]*(?=\r)` will still match `Grafik` for some reason...

Does anyone know a more optimal way to make the positive lookahead the newline?

Please don't answer anything unrelated to RegEx.

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to much anything after formula, and before a new line?

Comment: Yes, in other situations, CH2O may differ so I need a degenerate wildcard read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you

```
(?<=FORMULA\s+)\S+
```

Matches everything after `FORMULA` and before a new line

Comment: Oh my god, it was so obvious!

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a champ!

Comment: @PhilZan no probs

Comment: To keep the EOL after `FORMULA` out of the capture group, I think this should be `(?<=FORMULA\s+)\S+`